# Most efficient way to create an element from any jquery selector string

Tags: javascript, jquery, sizzle

## What I need to do

I would like to create an element that matches any selector string

#### Quick example.

```
var targetString = "a.exaggerated#selector[data-myattr='data-here']";
var targetEl = $(targetString);

if(!targetEl.length){

    var newEl = //create target
    $(body).append(newEl);
}
```

#### output

```
<body>
    <a class="exaggerated" id="selector" data-myattr="date-here"></a>
</body>
```

### why

I have buttons which when clicked do different tasks depending on its data-attributes. 
One of which is a `data-target`. I would like the ability to use ANY sizzlejs/jquery selector as the target, and if no target elements exist in the dom then create it. 
e.g.

`<button data-create-target="true" data-target=".mytarget">clickme</button>
 <button data-create-target="true" data-target="a.[data-type='popup']">clickme</button>`

I'm hoping that there is a way to use jquery's selector engine to do this because analysing the selector string again and extracting its attributes seems very long winded.

Many thanks

Comment: Many strings will work only as selectors not creators so to achieve what you want with *any* selector is not realistic.

Comment: You need to write a parser that converts  `a.exaggerated#selector[data-myattr='data-here']` into `<a id="selector" class="exaggerated" data-myattr="data-here"></a>`. This is basically compiling something like Jade (not exactly) into HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive created a plugin to solve the problem.

```
$("a.exaggerated#selector[data-myattr='data-here']").create().appendTo('body');
```

jquery version 2.1.1 and obove is required to access the $.find.tokenize method

```
$.fn.create = function( elem, dataAndEvents, deepDataAndEvents ) { 

    if(this.length){

        return $(this).clone( elem, dataAndEvents, deepDataAndEvents );

    } else {

    var selector = this.selector;
        var rquickExpr = /^(?:#([\w-]+)|(\w+)|\.([\w-]+))$/;
        var match, elem, m;

        if(!selector){
            return $(document.createElement('div'));
        } 
        if(match = rquickExpr.exec( selector )){

            if ( match[2] ) {
                return $(document.createElement(selector));
            } else {

                var elem = document.createElement('div');
                if ( (m = match[1]) ) {             
                    elem.id = m;            
                } else if ( (m = match[3])) {
                    elem.className = m ; 
                }
                return $(elem);
            }
        }
        selector = selector.replace( rtrim, "$1" );
        match = $.find.tokenize(selector);

        if ( match.length === 1 ) {

            var attrs = '';
            var tag = 'div';
            var classList = [];
            var type, value, matches;
            var tokens = match[0] = match[0].slice( 0 );

            for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {

                type = tokens[i].type;
                value = tokens[i].value
                matches = tokens[i].matches;

                if ( type === "ID" ){
                    attrs += 'id="' + matches[0] + '" ';
                    continue;
                }
                else if ( type === "CLASS" ){
                    classList.push(matches[0]+matches[1]+matches[2]);
                    continue;
                }
                else if ( type === "TAG" ){
                    tag = matches[0];
                    continue;
                }
                else if ( type === "ATTR" ){
                    attrs += matches[0]+ (matches[1] ? matches[1] : '' ) + (matches[2] ? '"' + matches[2] + '"': '' )+ ' ';
                }
                else if ( type === "PSEUDO" ){

                }
                else if ( type === "CHILD" ){

                } 
            };

            if(classList.length){
                attrs += 'class="';
                for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
                     attrs +=  classList[i] + ' ';
                };
                attrs += '"';
            }
            return $('<' + tag + ' ' + attrs + '></' + tag + '>');
        }
        return $(document.createElement('div'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with all selectors but if you are sure that the provided selectors work I would begin with something like this:

```
function createElement(selector) {
    var element = document.createElement('div');

    if (/^[a-z][a-z0-9\-]*/.test(selector)) {
        element = document.createElement(selector.match(/^[a-z][a-z0-9\-]*/)[0]);
    }

    // Wrap in jquery
    element = $(element);

    // Find the classes
    if (/\.([a-z][a-z0-9\-]*)/g.test(selector)) {
        selector.match(/\.([a-z][a-z0-9\-]*)/g).forEach(function (class) {
            element.addClass(class.substr(1));
        });
    }

    // Find the id
    if (/#([a-z][a-z0-9\-]*)/.test(selector)) {
        element.attr('id', selector.match(/#([a-z][a-z0-9\-]*)/)[0]);
    }

    // Find the attributes
    if (/\[([a-z][a-z0-9\-]*)=\'(.+)\'\]/) {
        var match = /\[([a-z][a-z0-9\-]*)=\'(.+)\'\]/.exec(selector);

        element.attr(match[1], match[2]);
    }

    return element;
}
```